# Apache mahout recommender - should I recreate the data model for every user?

Tags: java, mahout, mahout-recommender

I am new to Apache Mahout recommender. The use case involves providing suggestions to users based on their purchase history.
I am planning to use the following information :

- Purchase category
- Purchase amount
- Time of purchase (Example - recommend a pair of denims 6 months after the first pair was bought)
- Location of user

To identify users with similar purchase pattern/time of purchase and give them more preference, do I have to make custom data model for every user?
I was planning to import from the database periodically to recreate the data model.
Is there a way to dynamically give preference like mentioned below:

1. Location + purchase category + time match
2. Purchase category + time match
3. Location + time match (example winter clothing)

Currently I am using the sample code provided. (A lot of modifications are needed)

```
UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(model);
        UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new ThresholdUserNeighborhood(0.1, similarity, model);
        UserBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, similarity);
        List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(74, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, to achieve what you are sugguesting you need to do a step on your data where you add a feature like `t_since_last_purchase` which in an integer 0 -> inf.  E.g. days since last purchase.

This feature, time, will be another user feature which is correlated.

I think you are looking at some of the older Map-Reduce based reccomenders- which are in fact first class- but given your use case, you might want to check out [coorelated cooccurence based reccomenders](https://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html) which have a significant benefit of being able to look at multiple activities of the user (in your case, location, previous purchases, time).